# How to open port 11211 for EC2 instance by security group

Tags: amazon-ec2, memcached, aws-security-group

May I know how to open port 11211 for EC2 instance memcached server?

I'm trying to connect from Rails server to memcached server. However something is wrong with my security group setting.

What I did so far is

1. To launch 2 instances. One is Rails server, the other is memcached server.
2. To set up security groups

   - Rails server : Outbound => All traffic , All protocol, All port
   - memcached server : Inbound =>

     - ssh TCP, port 22, All source
     - Custom TCP Rule port, 11211, Rails server IP address

When I login to Rails server and execute below command, it looks working for port 22

````
$ telnet <memcached private IP address> 22
Trying <IP address>...
Connected to <IP address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4```
````

But when I check port 11211, it doesn't work.

```
$ telnet <memcached private IP address> 11211
```

The first question is why only port 22 is working? Even if I've set almost the same thing into security group???

When I login to memcached server and check the status, it looks working.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached status
● memcached.service - memcached daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-02-14 14:23:40 UTC; 19h ago
   Main PID: 7569 (memcached)
     Tasks: 6
   Memory: 628.0K
       CPU: 2.093s
   CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
           └─7569 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache

$ sudo netstat -ltup4

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:11211                 *:*                     LISTEN      6486/memcached
udp        0      0 *:11211                 *:*                                 6486/memcached
```

Could you let me know what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the security group of you rail server in the memcached server inbound rule.

Add a new rule, select your protocol and port range. For "Source", type or select your security group.

[image]